# Connector type on a TI graphing calculator

Tags: connector

A few images on the Internet list this as USB but it doesn’t look like it is. What is it? A part of a TI graphing calculator.

[image]

Comment: What model is the calculator?

Comment: That's the port that allows you to transfer notes between study pals, and play Pong against each other during class. Fond memories ☺️

Comment: Now I feel old. Is mini-USB really that ancient? :)

Comment: @TooTea getting that way. Micro officially supplanted Mini 17 years ago (which hasn't stopped me having to hunt down a cable for it, though!)

Answer (score 14):

That is a USB mini-AB connector.

[image]
<sub>[From Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/USB_Mini-AB_receptacle.svg)</sub>

It's a deprecated connector (as are all the USB mini series) which allows both mini-A and mini-B plugs to be inserted, and is intended to be used on devices which can operate in both host & device mode.
Pin-4 on this connector is used to indicate to the device which type of plug has been inserted so that it knows whether to act as a device or as a host.

Answer (score 6):

That is a [USB Mini AB receptacle](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=usb_conn&s=USB%202.0%20Mini%20AB) (My site). It accepts either a USB Mini A (host mode) or USB Mini B plug (device mode).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is a USB mini-AB type connector.  TI used those on their calculators.

As per comments, it will accept either a USB mini-A or USB mini-B type connector.
[image: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832594429602.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt]

[AMAZON REVIEW LINK](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2NWRZKKN95LKD/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B08CY5DPTS)

"I kept looking for a power plug that would fit that odd shape on the calculator and never would have guessed this power plug would work. But it does and it charges perfectly."

The pictures in that link look like your connector:
[image]

[image]

Comment: As the other answers say, it's actually a mini-AB, so it accepts both a mini-B plug (the one in your second photo, where the sides of the plug buckle inwards) and a mini-A (whose sides buckle outwards, the way the shell of the receptacle does). You can even notice the missing pin 4 in the mini-B plug in your second photo (second from the left) while the receptacle has all 5 pins, allowing the device to detect the type of the cable.